# How to Integrate GitLab with Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, gitlab, integrate

I would like to ask, about if somebody can explain to me, if it is possible to integrate jasmine with gitlab, to run automatically unit test every moment when it pass a deploy..

I has been looking arround but I can not find information.

thanks..